# Adding google fonts in django-quill-editor

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, quill, rich-text-editor

I'm working with [django-quill-editor](https://django-quill-editor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
and I want to add a custom google font. However I could not add it.

 I just want to know that is it possible to add custom google fonts in django-quill-editor.

I tried like this but it didn't work.

```
QUILL_CONFIGS = {
    'default':{
        'theme': 'snow',
        'modules': {
            'syntax': True,
            'toolbar': [
                [
                    {'font': ['Montserrat']},
                    {'header': []},
                    {'align': []},
                    'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike', 'blockquote',
                    {'color': []},
                    {'background': []},
                ],
                ['code-block', 'link'],
                ['clean'],
            ]
        }
    }
}
```